# Deadlock with jpaRepository

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, deadlock

We are using JpaRepository to connect mysql.
Our repository looks like:

```
public interface IRawEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<RawEntity, String> {

@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("delete from RawEntity u where u.x < :x and u.y = :y")
void deleteXBeforeAndY(@Param("created")Date created, @Param("namespace")String namespace);

List<RawEntity> findByXAndY(boolean X, String Y);

Page<RawEntity> findByX(String X, Pageable pageable);

@Query("select max (u.x) from RawEntity u where u.y = :y")
Date findMaxXByY(@Param("y")String Y);
```

}

The code works fine however we get deadlock in mysql (while using a lot of delete, save and select in parallel):

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1066)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
```

In mysql we see:

```
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2013-11-04 17:04:57 133b66000
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1147504, ACTIVE 34 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 10, locked 10
LOCK WAIT 8 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 16 row lock(s), undo log entries 14
MySQL thread id 240835, OS thread handle 0x134a82000, query id 13546692 localhost 127.0.0.1 salespredictsql updating
delete from rawentities where created<'2013-11-04 17:04:23.37' and namespace='namespace'
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
**RECORD LOCKS space id 15471 page no 4 n bits 168 index `PRIMARY` of table `spschema`.`rawentities` /* Partition `p3` */ trx id 1147504 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting**
Record lock, heap no 15 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 10; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 5; hex 3130303034; asc 10004;;
 1: len 4; hex caa3555b; asc   U[;;
 2: len 6; hex 000000118271; asc      q;;
 3: len 7; hex 2a000003a91d69; asc *     i;;
 4: len 5; hex 9902c22000; asc      ;;
 5: len 30; hex 616c6b646a66616c6b646a6620616c6b646a66206c616b73646a66616c6b; asc alkdjfalkdjf alkdjf laksdjfalk; (total 96 bytes);
 6: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 7: SQL NULL;
 8: len 9; hex 6e616d657370616365; asc namespace;;
 9: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1147505, ACTIVE 32 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
2479 lock struct(s), heap size 244152, 10029 row lock(s), undo log entries 9999
MySQL thread id 240836, OS thread handle 0x133b66000, query id 13837637 localhost 127.0.0.1 salespredictsql updating
/* delete com.salespredict.entities.master.RawEntity */ delete from rawentities where entityId='100004' and partitionId=1252218203
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 15471 page no 4 n bits 168 index `PRIMARY` of table `spschema`.`rawentities` /* Partition `p3` */ trx id 1147505 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 15 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 10; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 5; hex 3130303034; asc 10004;;
 1: len 4; hex caa3555b; asc   U[;;
 2: len 6; hex 000000118271; asc      q;;
 3: len 7; hex 2a000003a91d69; asc *     i;;
 4: len 5; hex 9902c22000; asc      ;;
 5: len 30; hex 616c6b646a66616c6b646a6620616c6b646a66206c616b73646a66616c6b; asc alkdjfalkdjf alkdjf laksdjfalk; (total 96 bytes);
 6: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 7: SQL NULL;
 8: len 9; hex 6e616d657370616365; asc namespace;;
 9: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;
```

How can we prevent it?
We tried to play with the Isolation and/or with the @Lock with no success.
Thanks,
Yaniv

Comment: You probably need to show the code using the JPA repository, if that is where the deadlock happens. What will probably fix your problem from a technical perspective is to also annotate the method producing the deadlock with @Transactional, so that there is only one transaction started at the boundary of the business method, not multiple transactions at the boundary of the repository methods.

Comment: We tried to annotate all the JPA methods with @Transactional - it didn't work.

Comment: That is certainly not going to work. You have to understand what you are doing when distributing the annotations in your code. The default behaviour is that a transaction context is inherited from the callee if the callee provides a transaction, otherwise, if the Transactional annotation exists, then a new transaction is created. If you annontate the methods of your repository and not the ones calling the repository, every call to the repository will be a new transaction.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent deadlock you can put `WITH (NOLOCK)` keyword after the name of tables.
For example:  `RawEntity u WITH (NOLOCK)`.
when you implement this, probably it will be okay

Comment: Thanks, where to write it? in the @Query annotation? I get: "unexpected token: WITH" Error.